# Firebase Crashlytics dSYM doesn't upload for release builds, only debug builds on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

I'm using two separate Firebase projects for debug and release modes of my iOS app. The production Firebase project is associated with iOS Release mode, and development Firebase project is associated with iOS Debug mode. I have two different GoogleService-Info.plist files which have been associated with the relevant iOS scheme via a Run Script Phase.

The dSYM files are being automatically uploaded for the development Firebase project & iOS Debug mode  but not the production Firebase project & iOS Release mode

Development Firebase project:
[image]

Production Firebase project:
[image]

Here are the relevant Xcode settings that [Firebase says are necessary](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios) for the automatic dSYM uploading to take place and which I've properly set up.
[image]
[image]
[image]

There is no special code that is run for debug vs production mode.

This is particularly strange because the exact same configuration IS working for debug mode, but not for release mode. What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was using two separate GoogleService-Info.plist files, one for Debug configuration and one for Release. I had followed the approach outlined by Tyler [here](https://medium.com/atlas/using-multiple-firebase-environments-in-ios-12b204cfa6c0).

However, the dev firebase plist was also added to my iOS target by default, while the prod firebase plist was not. This must have been overriding the custom script that Tyler explained.

The solution was to uncheck both the firebase plists from my iOS target (File Inspector -> Target Membership, uncheck)